# Aplication React calls to Appwrite and I have a problem with cors, I found solutions only for Express, but my app it´s only Front end

Tags: reactjs, database, cors, preact, appwrite

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1/databases/iddb/collections/idcollection/documents' from origin 'https://mon-portfolio-new.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://localhost' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

I'm using netlify, calling response from Appwrite database, I have this problem in Cors, how I can solve it?

How it be able to solve this problem with cors in react ? Or it's Appwrite that not allow use any server , I dont know what to do

Comment: it appears, based on the error you are receiving, appwrite doesn't accept requests from `https://mon-portfolio-new.netlify.app`. that'd mean you need to not use `https://mon-portfolio-new.netlify.app` and instead use a domain that they do accept... which appears to be localhost...

Answer (score 0):

Some possible reasons for this:

1. You may be missing the web platform in your project. You can add one by going to the Overview page for your project.
2. There may be some environment variable (project id, database id, or collection id) that wasn't set properly.
3. The user may not have access to the collection. You'll need to make sure the permissions on the collection are set properly.